# Pandas not merging on different columns - Key error or NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to mimic my issue with my current data. I am trying to use pandas to merge two dataframes on different column names (Code and Number), and bring only one column from df2 (location). I get either Key error, or NaN.

- Both were imported CSV files as data frames;
- Both column names do not have white space;
- Both columns have the same d.type

I have tried looking at other answers here, with literally copying and pasting the coded answers filling in my parts, and still get errors or NaN.

```py
df1:
[['Name', 'Income', 'Favourite superhero', 'Code', 'Colour'], 
['Joe', '80000', 'Batman', '10004', 'Red'], 
['Christine', '50000', 'Superman', '10005', 'Brown'], 
['Joey', '90000', 'Aquaman', '10002', 'Blue']

df2:
[['Number', 'Language', 'Location'], 
['10005', 'English', 'Sudbury'], 
['10002', 'French', 'Ottawa'], 
['10004', 'German', 'New York']]


what I tried:

data = pd.merge(CSV1, 
                  CSV2[['Location']],
                  left_on='Code',
                  right_on='Number',
                  how='left')

data = pd.merge(CSV1, 
                  CSV2[['Location']],
                  left_on='Code',
                  right_index=True,
                  how='left')

I am trying to have df1 with the location column from df2 for each instance where Number 
and Code are the same.
```

Comment: You are merging csv1 with only one column (Location) of csv2 so obviously it doesnt have column Number to merge the data on. You need. pd.merge(CSV1, 
                  CSV2[['Location', 'Number']],
                  left_on='Code',
                  right_on='Number',
                  how='left') You can drop Number later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For both you commands work , you need `Number` existing in the right side dataframe. For the 1st command you need to drop `Number` columns after `merge`. For 2nd command, you need to `set_index` on the right sliced dataframe and no need to drop `Number`. I modified your command accordingly:

```
CSV1.merge(CSV2[['Number', 'Location']], left_on='Code', right_on='Number', how='left').drop('Number', 1)
```

Or

```
CSV1.merge(CSV2[['Number', 'Location']].set_index('Number'), left_on='Code', right_index=True, how='left')


Out[892]:
        Name Income Favourite superhero   Code Colour  Location
0        Joe  80000              Batman  10004    Red  New York
1  Christine  50000            Superman  10005  Brown   Sudbury
2       Joey  90000             Aquaman  10002   Blue    Ottawa
```